# How to tag all my content as read with Flag?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have a Drupal 8 site with Message and Flag modules.

I created a view that displays messages. Messages have a "read" or "unread" flag. How to create a link in the header of my view for "Mark all as read" ?

I do not want to use "Mass Operation" which adds checkboxes and 2 buttons to my view.

I want a simple link "Mark as read" (ajax) to flag all messages on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used flags module. But if it is provides a link to mark read and unread, you can add global custom text with this link placed inside view and place it accordingly.

Comment: I already did that, but I do not know how to create the link and if it's possible.